# Retrofit NetworkIntercptor and "Accept-Encoding: gzip" header

Tags: java, android, retrofit, interceptor, okhttp

I am using retrofit in an android app 
Why if add custom implementation of a `NetworkInterceptor` the request add the header

```
 "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
```

and I must manually decompress the body response?

If I add the same custom interceptor as `Interceptor` (not NetworkInterceptor) the "`Accept-Encoding`" header is not automatically added and (obviusly) I do not need to decompress the body, because the http server respond with plain text

Comment: i just faced the same issue how you fixed this issue?

Comment: the problem is on the backend side. In my case an nginx web fronted wrongly manipulate the response header

Comment: thanks for the reply, I ended up with adding a check for "Accept-Encoding" header and unzip the content,